# How do I write these equations in pure Python?

Tags: python, math, degrees, radians

Given these example equations with all but the word degrees in broken python:

`L = 280.460` degrees `+ 0.9856474` degrees `* n`

and

`lamtha = L + 1.915` degrees `* math.sin(g) + 0.020` degrees `* math.sin(2*g)`

How can I can I write these in functional python to get the correct values for L and lamtha?

Comment: This is better suited for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) because your question fundamentally is about radians vs degrees and not really about Python.

Comment: The `sin` function does not _return_ radians. It expects radians as input. So you _have_ to convert the arguments for `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: `math.sin` takes radians. Basically all of those functions are defined in terms of radians, not degrees, so this conversion should be the first you do with input (`math.radians`) and the reverse the last you do with output (`math.degrees`).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It's about how to deal with degrees and radians in Python. I understand radians. I edited the math.radians returns radians bit.

Comment: Like Lev says, sin and cos take an *angle* as an argument and return a dimensionless number as a result. Geometrically, this is the ratio of the lengths of two sides sides of a triangle. I'm not sure what you mean by converting that into degrees.

Comment: I changed the question to more accurately ask for what I need help with.

Comment: What exactly does your new question mean? Are you asking how to convert degrees into radians...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math.sin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin) requires that you pass radians to it when you call it. If you pass your input as degrees, you will not get the correct result - convert to radians before you call `math.sin`.

The return value of `math.sin` won't be in degrees *or* radians - it's just a ratio, so there's nothing to convert there.

Comment: I think you're right @Matthew. To add, since the ratios are figured by radians, all other angles in the equation must be in radians so to be correct. The answer below would be the pure Python code: –  MansaMusa

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to convert all degrees where degrees are called for into into radians when operating on them or along with `math.sin` and similar functions that require radians as an argument. Finally, if I need to, I can convert the resulting lamtha into degrees with `math.degrees`.

```
L = math.radians(280.460) + math.radians(0.9856474) * n
g = math.radians(g)
lamtha = L + math.radians(1.915) * math.sin(g) + math.radians(0.020) * math.sin(2*g)
```

Comment: The ratios won't be in radians *or* degrees. You won't need to convert them - they're ratios. If you convert the result of sine to degrees, that result will be wrong.

Comment: Let me change my answer to reflect that.